# ImageView dimensions won't change in some devices

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am creating programmatically some ImageView's to use them as dots for a custom image slider but for some reason the dimensions of the images won't change in some devices.

Here is the code I use to generate those ImageViews and align them one next to the other:

```
private void drawMainImageDots(RelativeLayout layout, int total)
{
    int distance = 0;
    int step = 25;
    for (int i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20);

        if (i==0)
        {
            lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dotselected);
        }
        else
        {
            lp.setMargins(distance,0,0,0);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dotunselected);
        }

        distance = distance + step;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 20;

        layout.addView(imageView);
        dotsMainImageViewList.add(imageView);
    }
}
```

The `RelativeLayout layout` xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/mainimagegallerydotscon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?